# Is React Native app ignoring installed SSL certificate?

Tags: react-native, axios

I created an app using `React Native`, this app connects to a server with a certificate signed by an untrusted CA.

To overcome this problem I simply installed the CA certificate on the device. Now when I browse the URL I no longer get any certificate error, however, when I send a request through the app I get an error, and furthering I can see this java error:

`java.security.cert.certpathvalidatorexception trust anchor for certification path not found`

I can see this error only using `Axios`, I tried with fetch but I can only see `TypeError` with no detail

It's like the `React Native` app doesn't use the Android's built-in keystore, is that possible?

PS unfortunately I can't ask the customer to use an already known CA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the situation I created the file with the `Network Security Configuration` adding an additional CAs to trust

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas

I don't know if this is the right way, but it is working